# OpenVPN Push Route

Tags: openvpn, vpn

Setting up openVPN trying the steps Advanced routed VPN configuration on server:
1. push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"
get an error message No command 'push' found didn't you mean:
   Command 'posh' from package 'posh' (universe)
   Command 'pdsh' from package 'pdsh' (universe)
   Command 'ppsh' from package 'ppsh' (universe)
   Command 'rush' from package 'rush' (universe)
push: command not found

has anyone encountered this message? or have stubbled upon a similar error. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I use the same syntax, but the routes don't seem to push, so I'm also eager to see the answer.

Comment: `push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"` goes in your OpenVPN configuration file (e.g., `/etc/openvpn/whatever.conf`), it's not something you run at the command line.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie I suspect you have a different issue — if so, please post your own question. I use OpenVPN and route push works... (Make sure your clients have `--pull`/`--client`, though!)

Comment: @derobert would i cp the command "push "route 10..." into the /etc/openvpn folder? because at the moment I'm running the command from terminal and it gives the error that no such command exist which makes sense when you say its not run from the command line however how is this executed?

Comment: @LadyP if you're specifying all the options on the command line instead of a config file, then it'd be the `--push` option: `openvpn … --push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"`, I think. Please include the full command you're running (feel free to redact sensitive information like IP addresses, hostnames, etc.)

Comment: @derobert went ahead and added the (--) even typed it several different ways, received the same response every time,

Comment: Oops sorry accidentally typed return this is the error message:

Comment: openvpn#--push "route 10.0.0.0 255.0.0.0"      --: command not found    the comment is that command not found.